# #NA Index Match between two different Google sheets

Tags: indexing, match, na

I am trying to return a result in one Google spreadsheet based on the information in another Google spreadsheet. If I use the formula within the one spreadsheet ( two different sheets ), it works like a dream. It seems the "Importrange" is throwing off my formula.

=IF(C22>0, INDEX(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1M7jPlVQsM0QM9ozY_F5sfBSGJa-RZww_cTw3aHAoo3o/edit#gid=0","A112:A696"),MATCH(C22,IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1M7jPlVQsM0QM9ozY_F5sfBSGJa-RZww_cTw3aHAoo3o/edit#gid=0","B112:B696"),0),1),0)

I get the #NA error - Did not find Value "A003" in Match evaluation.

The A003 is everywhere it is supposed to be.

I am stuck. AAArgh!

I tried adjusting the sheet names, the column references, the Match search type, the formatting on the source spreadsheet.

Comment: Hi Toni, import data in different tab using importrange function, and then you can use your old formula, it will work like in same spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you. So it is not possible to bring info from one sheet to another in this way?